# Connect to Azure AD Conditional Access VPN Command Line

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, vpn, azure-vpn

Normally I connect to VPN using `rasdial` on Windows. When using Conditional Access with VPN the following flow happens when we Connect to VPN by clicking on Network Icon on Taskbar:

- The VPN client calls into Windows 10’s Azure AD Token Broker, identifying itself as a VPN client.
- The Azure AD Token Broker authenticates to Azure AD and provides it with information about the device trying to connect. The Azure AD Server checks if the device is in compliance with the policies.
- If compliant, Azure AD requests a short-lived certificate
- Azure AD pushes down a short-lived certificate to the Certificate Store via the Token Broker. The Token Broker then returns control back over to the VPN client for further connection processing.
- The VPN client uses the Azure AD-issued certificate to authenticate with the VPN server.

So using `rasdial` directly is causing `Remote Access error 798 -  A certificate could not be found that can be used with this Extensible Authentication Protocol.` As using `rasdial` works only after initial steps in the flow are completed. So how to trigger this flow command line?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on how to setup Azure VPN connection for the command line run: [Deconstructing the Azure Point-to-Site VPN for command line usage](https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2013/11/27/deconstructing-the-azure-point-to-site-vpn-for-command-line-usage)

It works. The only issue I found with the approach is the obligatory requirement to run VPN connection manually under your user at least once (for the first time) to bind appropriate certificate.